# How can I make available sourcemaps on production mode CRA?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app, yarnpkg

I'm using a simple version of CRA, without any Eject commands and so on. In development mode, I can see a sourcemap i.e. line where warnings occur.

And I faced the problem that onClick event works perfectly on the development mode, but when I type `yarn build` and serve the main file, onClick doesn't work, and in the console no errors, no warnings.

What can be the problem?

SidebarStructure code:

```
{
    id: 24,
    label: "Add section",
    icon: <AddSection />,
    click: function(event, ...rest) {
      const name = "addSectionClick";
      rest.forEach(c => {
        if (c.name === name) {
          return c(event);
        }
        return false;
      });
    }
  },
```

And it's spreading on SidebarLink itself:

```
<ListItem
          onClick={e => {
            if (click) {
              return click(e, addSectionClick, chatSetOpen, onLogin);
            }
            return toggleDrawer(e);
          }}
/>
```

`addSectionClick, chatSetOpen, onLogin` it's functions, that are contain react hooks

Comment: Vote on [this proposal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354583/disentangle-the-yarn) to ease the tag confusion.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the assignment was realized as a comparison between function name and the string.

But problem is that the function name was changing because of Babel optimization.

So I just add a value to the function to the comparison